# Where are the images for a .pkg / .dmg file located?

Tags: macos, graphics

I was wondering where the default .pkg image file is that looks like:

[image]

This is not located at

```
system/library/coreservices/CoreTypes.bundle/resources
```

Same goes for .dmg files. Unless I have to go and download a .pkg/.dmg file and then "Get Info" and copy the icon in the upper right; which is the method I used to get the image earlier. Is it locally exclusive to .pkg files only? (meaning that apple makes an application where every pkg is set to default to have that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images for most document types are provided by the application associated with that document type. For example, if you have TextEdit set as the default application for opening .txt files, the Finder will use an icon from TextEdit.app/Contents/Resources for those files (the exact icon file is controlled by TextEdit.app/Contents/Info.plist). But if you switch the default application to, say, BBEdit, then it'll switch to using the icon from BBEdit.app/Contents/Resources.

Installer packages and disk images work this way, so their icons are /System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app/Contents/Resources/package.icns and /System/Library/CoreServices/DiskImageMounter.app/Contents/Resources/diskcopy-doc.icns respectively.